# Is there possibility to only look for black font in firebase ml kit for android?

Tags: firebase-mlkit, text-recognition, google-mlkit

I've already read  everything around ml kit tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text . I'm interested only in local ocr not cloud version. Of course as question suggests it's about text recognition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option for you to control the text color that the ML Kit model looks for. You will either have to perform filtering in your app after calling ML Kit, or train your own model for that.